# Arbitrary dynamic properties in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

In JavaScript I can take `anyOldObject` and add `anyOldObject["anyOldProperty"]="Test"`. I could do this in ActionScript 2 as well. Can I do it in ActionScript 3?

For example, I'm creating SoundChannel instances and I want to, say, assign IDs to them (e.g. `soundChannel["id"]="123"`) or assign states. Will this still work, or will I have to create a separate associative array for each property (or create some new enclosing SoundChannelHolder class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it on every class created as [dynamic](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#dynamic).

[MovieClip](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html) is one of them.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the quick answer. I looked up `SoundChannel` and... of course it's _not_ dynamic. But now I don't have to experiment all day. Thanks!!

Comment: By the way, it's not very OOP. You should extend the class you are interested in and add the sealed properties you need.

Comment: You can always extend any class to make your own dynamic version of it (unless it's marked as final), though like Kodiak said, not very good practice...  public dynamic class MySoundChannel extends SoundChannel { ... }

Comment: @Kodiak: Oh, I completely agree that it's not very OOP. But it's very JavaScript, and I had an existing AS2 application that was essentially JavaScript that I needed to upgrade to AS3 just so I could add WAV support. I thought I'd just have to change a couple of lines... but apparently AS3 is a whole other language. I have plenty of other work to do and I was trying to dash off this little change and go back to the other stuff. Little did I know I'd spend the whole day installing Flex, learning AS3, etc.... :)

Comment: AS2 was more quick-and-dirty-friendly ;)